# Is there a way to define a command for radio buttons to show right or false answer in multiple choice quiz?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am a beginner trying to create a multiple choice quiz in python with Tkinter. Sorry if I created a messy code. I am using radio buttons for different answers. I would like to show the message "This is the correct answer" when selecting Option 1 and "This is the wrong answer" when selecting any other option. Currently, the message is always "This is the wrong answer" regardless of the Option that is chosen. I understood that the value has nothing to do with it but I did not find the right way to do it. Is there a way to define this kind of command? Thank you so much for any help, recommendations and answers.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("Quiz")
window.geometry("500x150")
score = 0
def inst():
    t = Label(window, text="Choose the correct statement to answer the 
question")
    t.pack()

def start():
    start_game()

greet = Label(window, text="Welcome to the Quiz")
greet.pack()
startButton = Button(window, command=start, text="Start")
startButton.pack()
instr = Button(window, text="Instructions", command=inst)
instr.pack()
end = Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy)
end.pack()

def start_game():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Question 1")
    var = StringVar()
    def check():
        if var.get() is True:
            messagebox.showinfo('Congrats', message='This is the correct 
answer.Score is {}'.format(score))
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Lose', message='This answer is wrong.')
    R1 = Radiobutton(top,
    text="Option 1",
    indicatoron=0,
    width=20,
    padx=20,
    pady=10,
    variable=var,
    value=True,
    command=check)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )
    R2 = Radiobutton(top,
    text="Option 2",
    indicatoron=0,
    width=20,
    padx=20,
    pady=10,
    variable=var,
    value=False,
    command=check)
    R2.pack( anchor = W )
    R3 = Radiobutton(top,
    text="Option 3",
    indicatoron=0,
    width=20,
    padx=20,
    pady=10,
    variable=var,
    value=False,
    command=check)
    R3.pack( anchor = W)
    label = Label(top)
    label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're working with boolean values, I thought it made more sense to use a `BooleanVar` instead.

You can simply pass the buttons to the `check` function and change their colours if you know which one is correct:

```
def check(btn1, btn2):
    btn1.config(bg='green')
    btn2.config(bg='red')
```

Then modify the radiobuttons as such (just below where you've defined them):

```
for btn in (R1, R2):
    btn.config(command=lambda btn1=R1,btn2=R2:check(btn1,btn2))
```

Note, I used two buttons as `R2` and `R3` had the same values so they'd be grouped as one effectively.

Here is an example; it uses a button list to store all radiobuttons that were created and changes the colour of each of them depending on their text whilst also checking if the player got the right answer.

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_answer():
    if question_answer.get() == 2: #get the value of the integer variable
        print('you got it right')  #if it has been set to 2 by the player, they got it right
    for btn in btnlist: #check each of our radiobuttons
        if int(btn['text']) == 2: #if the text of that button is equal to the correct answer
            btn.config(bg='green') #make it green
        else:
            btn.config(bg='red') #otherwise make it red

win = tk.Tk()
question = 'What is 1+1?' #put your question here

question_answer = tk.IntVar() #we use an Integer Variable to store the value of the answer
question_answer.set(0) #we set the value of the correct answer to 0

lbl = tk.Label(win, text=question)
lbl.grid(columnspan=4)

column = 0
btnlist = []
for answer in range(4): #create radiobuttons in a for loop
    btn = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=str(answer), variable=question_answer,
                         value=answer) #associate each button with the answer variable
    #but give each button its own unique value
    btnlist.append(btn)
    btn.grid(row=1, column=column)
    column += 1

confirm_btn = tk.Button(win, text='Confirm', command=check_answer)
confirm_btn.grid(columnspan=4)
win.mainloop()
```

In this example I used an `IntVar` as the answer is an integer, you could also use a `BooleanVar` or `StringVar` in the same manner as needed.

**EDIT:** As per you request in the comments:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
text_to_add_to_btns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] #change to whatever text you like
#with however many elements which represent each individual button
btn_list = []
Column = 0
for txt in text_to_add_to_btns:
    btn = tk.Button(win, text=txt)
    btn.grid(row=0, column=Column, sticky='nesw')
    btn_list.append(btn)
    Column += 1
win.mainloop()
```

We create a default list containing text to add to each button as individual list elements. We then loop over that list to create each button for every element and set the text of the button to that element and then append it to our separate button list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was extremely helpful. Could you give me advice on how to assign text to the different buttons? I can't seem to figure out how to keep them in the list but give them different text at the same time.

Comment: You could create a list containing all the text you'd like to add to buttons, then iterate over that list - like how I did `for answer in range(4)` but instead of `range(4)` you'd use your list of texts to put on buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reponse. I am sorry for asking so many questions but I am still very new to this. Sorry for asking so many questions but I am very new to everything. So should I add an additional list with the text and then use it instead of    range(4)     in the other list or keep one list and change the     btnlist    and include the text there? Because the way I did it I lost either the colours changing or the text was not applied to the buttons.

Comment: @Lana See updated answer, hope it helps. If you wanted integers to be on your buttons you'd use `range(number_of_buttons_here)`, if you want strings instead, use the method described in the edit.